# JS function with loop in a loop iterator problem

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function func(){
 for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
   alert('B');
 }
}

for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
  func();
  alert('A');
}
```

What I expected was: BBBBBABBBBBABBBBBABBBBBABBBBBA

but what received was just BBBBBA

I found out that's because there is function scope, not block scope in JS. What I'd like to know is **how to preserve such a behavior**. I mean to force something like block scope. Otherwise it's very easy to make really nasty bugs - e.g. while using a function somebody else wrote or the one you wrote yourself, but a few months earlier.

Comment: one minute and 4 exact answers.. at least we are consistent. :)

Comment: wow .... i just refreshed the page and saw them ... ok who get's the +1 lol

Comment: @Tarek: +1's are free; I give 'em to all that are helpful.

Comment: i meant the accepted answer... sorry(o'.'o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you use `var i=0` instead of just `i=0`.  Otherwise, it floats into the global scope and gets used by *both* loops.

```
function func(){
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
       alert('B');
    }
}

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    func();
    alert('A');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `i` being global variable. User `var` to confine its scope to `func` function:

```
function func(){
  for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    alert('B');
  }
}
```

Functions with variables declared that way will not pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Set the variable i to local scope in the function `func`

```
function func(){
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
   alert('B');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use global variables (which as you noticed, can be accidently changed by all code. That isn't anything to do with lexical scoping, that would happen in C as well with similar code). Instead make each variable local:

```
function func(){
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){ // var
   alert('B');
 }
}

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){ // var
  func();
  alert('A');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function func(){
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
   console.log('B');
 }
}

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
  func();
  console.log('A');
}
```

this should work for you

http://jsfiddle.net/jvXHM/

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` to make `i` local:

```
function func(){
 for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
   alert('B');
 }
}

for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
  func();
  alert('A');
}
```